# Estimate the principal term of the asymptotic integral $\int\limits_{-1}^{1}\cos (kx)e^{i\lambda |x|}dx,\lambda \to \infty $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, asymptotics

> Estimate the principal term of the asymptotic integral
> $$\int\limits_{-1}^{1}\cos (kx)e^{i\lambda |x|}dx,\lambda \to \infty $$
> At "moderate" values of $\lambda $, calculate the integral using the quadrature formula and compare with the asymptotic. On the parameter plane $\lambda$ , $N$ (number of nodes of the quadrature formula) indicate the area where the estimates diverge by less than $0.01$

I have tried a Taylor series of functions at $0$
$$\cos(kx)e^{i\lambda|x|} = \cos(kx)e^{i\lambda x} = \left(1 - \frac{(kx)^2}{2} + \frac{(kx)^4}{4!} - \ldots\right) \left(1 + i\lambda x - \frac{(\lambda x)^2}{2} + \ldots\right)$$

And then it is possible to make this assessment
$$\cos(kx)e^{i\lambda|x|} \approx \left(1 - \frac{(kx)^2}{2}\right)\left(1 + i\lambda x - \frac{(\lambda x)^2}{2}\right)\Rightarrow \int_{-1}^{1} \cos(kx)e^{i\lambda|x|}dx \approx \int\limits_{-1}^{1} \left(1 - \frac{(kx)^2}{2}\right)\left(1 + i\lambda x - \frac{(\lambda x)^2}{2}\right)dx$$

But now how do I estimate the main term of the integral? How do I go to the integral for "moderate" values ? (I tried through the quadrature fom, but nothing worked)

Comment: This integral can be computed analytically. I get it behaving as $$2i\lambda\,\frac{1 - \cos k e^{i\lambda}}{\lambda^2 - k^2}$$ as $\lambda \rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: The Taylor approximation works for small values of the argument. However, $\lambda|x|$ is large if $\lambda$ is large and $x$ is not close to $0$. Consider http://dlmf.nist.gov/2.3.E4 instead.

Comment: Could you show me visually how this decomposition can be applied?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that $k$ is fixed. Note that your integral is
$$
2\int_0^1 {\cos (kx){\rm e}^{{\rm i}\lambda x} {\rm d}x}. 
$$
Integration by parts yields
$$
2\int_0^1 {\cos (kx){\rm e}^{{\rm i}\lambda x} {\rm d}x}  = 2\frac{{\cos (k){\rm e}^{{\rm i}\lambda }  - 1}}{{{\rm i}\lambda }} + \frac{{2k}}{{{\rm i}\lambda }}\int_0^1 {\sin (kx){\rm e}^{{\rm i}\lambda x} {\rm d}x} .
$$
Show, using integration by parts, that
$$
\int_0^1 {\sin (kx){\rm e}^{{\rm i}\lambda x} {\rm d}x}  = \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{\lambda }} \right)
$$
as $\lambda \to +\infty$, and hence conclude that
$$
\int_{-1}^1 {\cos (kx){\rm e}^{{\rm i}\lambda |x|} {\rm d}x}  = 2\frac{{\cos (k){\rm e}^{{\rm i}\lambda }  - 1}}{{{\rm i}\lambda }} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{\lambda ^2 }}} \right)
$$
as $\lambda \to +\infty$.